# outputting response to browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

am posting half code coz the rest is working.

just need to see if wat i want can work

Question: is it possible to send alert() errors to browsers. because alert() just output errors in popup window up the browser

so i want to do it like in success function where u do

`$('#resp').text(response.feedback);` and send response to html like `<div id="resp"></div>`

so my main question is it possible to send alert() errors to browser than popup up on browser.

to send it in browser and call it with id like above success function

```
beforeSend: function(){ 

        if ($("form input[name='email']").val() == "") {
        alert("Text-field is empty.");
        return false;
            }
        },
         success: function(response) {
         $("#Submit").attr("disabled", true);
    $('#resp').text(response.feedback);
  },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understood you correctly:

```
beforeSend: function(){ 

        if ($("form input[name='email']").val() == "") {
           $('#resp').text('TextField is Empty');
           return false;
        },
},
success: function(response) {
    $("#Submit").attr("disabled", true);
    $('#resp').text(response.feedback);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to send some flag/message back to the browser in your server response.  Then check for that flag/message, and present an alert() in your client side code.

e.g.

```
function showMessage(msg){
  alert(msg);
}

//in your success bit
success: function(response){
  if(response.someFlagYouSet == "NO_SUPPLIES_LEFT"){
    showMessage("There are no supplies left... sorry");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than

```
alert("Text-field is empty.");
```

do

```
$('#resp').text("Text-field is empty.");
```